# Missing path from XCFramework as defined by DebugSymbolsPath in its Info.plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, circleci, xcframework, dsym

I have a XCFramework with another XCFramework in it. And both of them contains dSYMs folder.
When I try to `xcodebuild` the main framework I get an error:

`Missing path from XCFramework as defined by DebugSymbolsPath in its Info.plist file`

How can I fix that? The thing is, when I xcodebuild it from my local machine I do not see any error, but when I try to run it from CircleCI - my CI job stops with this error.

Comment: Check if the path does really exist. I had to create it manually and after it everything worked fine.

Comment: For me it was exactly what the error was saying. There was a .dSYMs in .gitignore and as a result it was not committed on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the key and value for `DebugSymbolsPath` from info.plist

```
<key>DebugSymbolsPath</key>
<string>dSYMs</string>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue for all frameworks built using the `flutter` command line.

Are there any consequences of removing this key-value pair? If not, how can we prevent these in the first place?